# remote debugging with xdebug and gdb

Tags: gdb, xdebug

I want use xdebug to analyze a php script and break, as soon as a remote host sends an HTTP request for that particular page, to GDB running on the server. Config options for php.ini are:

```
    xdebug.remote_enable = On
    xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

Since the debugger isn't on a different machine, but I want to debug only when a remote request is sent, how can I do this without debugging through a web browser? Should I run GDB on port 9000 and send the value XDEBUG_SESSION_START = session_name in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xdebug can't speak directly to GDB. However, it comes with a small simple client that does remarkable similar things. I've just explained how you can use it at [Setting Xdebug breakpoints solely in command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284795/setting-xdebug-breakpoints-solely-in-command-line)

However, I am a bit unclear what you are trying to do. Can you explain where all the things live and what your set-up is?