# Setting Xdebug breakpoints solely in command line

Tags: php, command-line, centos, xdebug, centos6

I'm struggling with a PHP maintenance script and I was looking for a way to use xdebug solely in command line (like gdb old-school), but I couldn't figure out how to set a breakpoint, do a step-into, step-over and continue. Xdebug is up and running, as `phpinfo();` says.

I found a lot of documentation regarding how to do this using Eclipse and other tools, but none to CLI. Could anyone help me? My environment is Centos 6 and Bash.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually possible. In the Xdebug source downloads, you will find a directory called "debugclient". In this directory you will find a **very** simple client accepting raw DBGP commands, and giving output as XML. To compile, you run:

- apt-get install libedit-dev (or equivalent)
- ./buildconf
- ./configure --with-libedit
- make

You can then run the binary with `./debugclient`.

On a different shell, you then run the following:

- export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=dr"
- php -dxdebug.remote_enable=1 yourscript.php

The debugclient sees this connection, and you then can issue direct DBGP commands. For a breakpoint, you can for example set:

`breakpoint_set -i 1 -t line -f file:///path/to/yourscript.php -n 42`

the `-i 1` is required to be an increasing number, `-f` is the file and `-n` the line number. After setting the breakpoint you can then run `run -i 2` to advance to that line. For all other commands, I'd refer you to the DBGP documentation at http://xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php

Comment: Since xdebug is enclosed with default php 5.3 package (that i installed at Ubuntu) so in this case what steps would be there to assign breakpoint on php script at command line?